# How to write mongodb query for the following SQL query

Tags: sql-server, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have following data:

```
articles[{
_id:1,
flag1:true,
date:2016-09-09,
title:"...",
flag2:false
},
{
_id:2,
flag1:true,
date:2016-09-10,
title:"...",
flag2:false
},
{
_id:3,
flag1:false,
date:2016-09-11,
title:"...",
flag2:true
},
{
_id:4,
flag1:false,
date:2016-09-13,
title:"...",
flag2:true
}
]
```

I want individual sorting [basically I have to select two list one sorted list with `flag1:true`  and `flag2:true` finally merge them into one list]
 and `flag1:true` records list on top.

I want to get output in following order:

```
[
{
_id:2,
flag1:true,
date:2016-09-10,
title:"...",
flag2:false
},
{
_id:1,
flag1:true,
date:2016-09-09,
title:"...",
flag2:false
},
{
_id:4,
flag1:false,
date:2016-09-13,
title:"...",
flag2:true
},
{
_id:3,
flag1:false,
date:2016-09-11,
title:"...",
flag2:true
}
]
```

How do I write this SQL query in mongoose/mongodb?

```
select * from articles
where _id in 
 (select _id from articles where Flag1=true
  order by date desc)
 or 
 _id in (select _id from articles where Flag2=true
  order by date desc)
```

I want to write individual sorting, so that I will get `Flag1` based records in first priority with the sorted order.

Comment: provide sample document and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my question. I used aggregate function with $project for sorting I used virtual field with $project.
We can create subqueries by using $project.

Answer (score 1):

```
> db.articles.find({ $or: [ { Flag1: true }, { Flag2: true } ] }).sort({date:-1})
```

However I am unclear with your requirements..still hope this will help you.

**UPDATE:**

Okais...then you just need to add sort by those two fields :-

```
db.articles.find({ $or: [ { Flag1: true }, { Flag2: true } ]  })
.sort({Flag1:-1,Flag2:-1,date:-1})
```

Comment: I have added example to question.

Comment: Yea, I have tried that approach I should get flag1 records on top with sorted on date. If I add Flag1(consider flag1 as timestamp type instead of boolean) in sort I will get sorted on flag1 I may miss date priority in the records order.

Comment: Is it possible to get records as two seperate list?